# Are Prime numbers odd numbers or is there something else going on?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are even numbers and odd numbers, so if at least one prime was even, it would be divided by 2 perfectly. I am sorry if this is a stupid question. Just wanting to clarify some things

Comment: $2$ is the only even prime number, for the reason you suggest.  Similarly, $3$ is the only prime multiple of $3$.

Comment: Think of it this way.  Prime means "divisible only by itself and 1".  Even means "divisible by $2$".  So to be an even prime we must have both "divisible only by itself and 1" and "divisible by $2$" which means "2 is itself".  So $2$ is the only even prime.  likewise the primes $3,5,7,11, etc$ are the only primes divisible by $3,5,7,11, etc$.  (For any prime $p$, $p$ will always be the only prime that is divisible by $p$.  If anything else is divisible by $p$ .... then it isn't prime)

Comment: ... or maybe I should put it this way.... $2 = 2*1$ is only divisible by itself and $1$ so it is prime.  Any *other* even number $n = 2*m$ is divisible by $2$ which is a number that is *neither* $n$, itself, nor $1$.  So $n = 2m$ is *not* prime if $n \ne 2$.  So $2$ is an even prime but it is the *only* even prime.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys :)